# How to handle active route/route change with react-dom-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an `App` top-level component, that has a menu and routes. On menu click I update the active item to reflect the selected route. Here's the code:

```js
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(window.location.pathname === '/' ? 'home' : getRouteName());
...
const handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
  setActiveItem(name);
  window.document.title = 'MyApp - ' + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
};

const MenuItem = ({name, title, link}) => (
  <Menu.Item
    as={Link}
    to={link}
    name={name}
    title={title}
    active={activeItem === name}
    onClick={handleItemClick}
  >
    {title}
  </Menu.Item>
);
...
<Menu /> //iterate over items
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  ...
</Switch>
```

And it works well, UNTIL one of the components redirects to another component. So if I go to `/comp1` (whether by clicking or directly browsing) the `activeItem` will be `comp1` and the `comp1` menu item will look active. But if I go to `comp2` and add a button to navigate to `comp1` (either using a `<Link>` component, or `history.push('/comp1')`, the active item remians on `comp2`.

Any ideas how to trigger a change in the `App` compoinent to reflect a route change, preferably without needing to put the `handleActiveItem` function into context, or pass it along to all other components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

I'm now using the `useLocation` hook provided by `react-router-dom` to trigger an effect that changes the active item and the page title. It gets fired every time the location changes, regardless if by the user or an inner component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NavLink to achieve the same result and it's a bit simpler as the active item is handled for you.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

`<NavLink>`
`A special version of the <Link> that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL`

```
<NavLink to="/foo">foo</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/bar">bar</NavLink>
```

Comment: I've used NavLink before. It changes the style of a link. However, I need to change a menu (using Semantic) AND the page title. How does NavLink help to change the top component active item?